# mysql order by case

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, case

i tried to get ASC ordered results on NAME within each category of below query but not able to derive that.

```
select ID,NEWID,NAME from table 
ORDER BY CASE 
     WHEN ID = PID THEN 1 
     WHEN NEWID IS NOT NULL THEN 2 
     ELSE 3
     END;
```

PID is input, which returns one record and that should appear first, rest should be based on NEWID. But I want records to sorted ASC based on NAME for 2 sections (NEWID is not null and Null). 
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were VERY CLOSE...  If you want to float your "NewID" to the top, correct on the case for setting to 1.  Then all others get an ID of 2.  Now, add the SECONDARY order based on the name so WITHIN each respective 1 or 2, the names are sorted such as:

```
select ID,NEWID,NAME from table 
ORDER BY CASE 
     WHEN ID = PID THEN 1 
     WHEN NEWID IS NOT NULL THEN 2 
     ELSE 3
     END,
     NAME;
```

Ex: if your data had

```
ID  Name   NewID
1   X      17
2   R      21
3   F      null
4   B      null
5   H      19
6   L      41
```

And you are looking for "PID" (parameter ID) = 5.  The order would result with ID#5 in the first position

```
CASE FLAG    ID  Name   NewID
1            5   H      19   (ID=5 floats to the top of the list)

2            6   L      41   (all others that HAD a NewID value)
2            2   R      21
2            1   X      17

3            4   B      null (all the rest without a NewID)
3            3   F      null
```

Notice within each "case flag", they are sorted by the name (even though I used simple one alpha character for context)

Comment: @Chandru, you are welcome... also, check out Help -> Tour for site etiquette for Q&A so others know questions are resolved and others can find what works if they have similar problems with their work.

Answer (score 1):

You shuld add a my_order column

```
select 
    ID
  , NEWID
  , NAME
  , CASE 
       WHEN ID = PID THEN 1 
       WHEN NEWID IS NOT NULL THEN 2 
       ELSE 3
     END as my_order 
from table 
ORDER BY my_order;
```

Comment: thanks @scaisEdge , this will add New column into my result, which I think I don't need when passing to application

Comment: For the ordering that you need this is the way  .. in application is enough don't use the column ..

Comment: thanks, exactly what I need - cause I have no idea what case causes my order now :-)